# R-script hanging unexpectedly on Unix Server

Tags: r

I'm running an R-script on a unix server using the command Rscript. The program counts different Ts and Tv between recoded genotypes. The scripts seems to work fine until it pauses (CPU to 0.0%) at random for unknown time. It sometimes later starts again but i can't find any pattern in the pausing.

It only stops in the following for loop:

```
#difference between different id
diffs <- NULL
for (i in 1:1091){
  # Start the clock
  ptm <- proc.time()
  print(i) 
  print(ptm)
  diffs <- NULL
  diffs <- abs(mdata[,4:ncol(mdata)]-cbind(mdata[,(4+i):ncol(mdata)],mdata[,4:(3+i)]))
  diffs <- cbind(diffs,pos_cpg)
  TCcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC2),ncol=1092))
  print('TC gelukt')
  TAcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TA),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TA2),ncol=1092))
  print('TA gelukt')
  TGcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TG),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TG2),ncol=1092))
  print('TG gelukt')
  CGcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% CG),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% CG2),ncol=1092))
  print('CG gelukt')
  CAcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% CA),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% CA2),ncol=1092))
  print('CA gelukt')
  GAcount[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA),ncol=1092)) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA2),ncol=1092))
  print('GA gelukt')
  GAcpg[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-((matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)]))-(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA),ncol=1092)))) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA2),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-((matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA2),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% GA2),ncol=1092))))
  print('GAcpg gelukt')
  TCcpg[i,] <- colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-((matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC),ncol=1092)))) + 2*colSums(matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC2),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-((matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC2),ncol=1092)==(diffs[,ncol(diffs)])-matrix((diffs[,1:(ncol(diffs)-1)] %in% TC2),ncol=1092))))
  print('TCcpg gelukt')
  ratio1 <- mean(CAcount[i,]/TAcount[i,])
  ratio2 <- mean(TGcount[i,]/CGcount[i,])
  print(ratio1)
  print(ratio2)
  rm(diffs)
  Ts[i,] <- TCcount[i,] + GAcount[i,]
  print('Ts gelukt')
  Tv[i,] <- TAcount[i,] + TGcount[i,] + CAcount[i,] + CGcount[i,]
  print('Tv gelukt')
  TsCpG[i,] <- TCcpg[i,] + GAcpg[i,]
  print('TsCpG gelukt')
  CTnCpG[i,] <- TCcount[i,] - TCcpg[i,]
  print('CTnCpG gelukt')
  GAnCpG[i,] <- GAcount[i,] - GAcpg[i,]
  print('GAnCpG gelukt')
  # Stop the clock
  print(proc.time())
  tijd <- proc.time() - ptm
  print(paste(i,'gedaan','in',tijd[3],sep=' '))
  save(TC,file='TC.Rda')
  save(TA,file='TA.Rda')
  save(TG,file='TG.Rda')
  save(CA,file='CA.Rda')
  save(CG,file='CG.Rda')
  save(GA,file='GA.Rda')
  save(CTnCpG,file='CTnCpG.Rda')
  save(GAnCpG,file='GAnCpG.Rda')
  save(Ts,file='Ts.Rda')
  save(Tv,file='Tv.Rda')
  save(TsCpG,file='TsCpG.Rda')
  print('alles opgeslaan')
}
```

The print statement are control output to try to determine where the pausing happens. The matrix mdata has numeric recoded genotypes in it from column 4 till the second last column and the last column contains a 0 or 1 value which tells if the location is a known CpG location.

Does someone see a reason why this script would pause at random?

Comment: There are a lot of `save` in the loop. Maybe it isn't stopping, but just taking time to save all those objects.

Comment: Normally it stops in the counting of a certain Ts/Tv or CpGTs not in the saving part.